# Remapping "IntlBackslash" to a shift key in Chrome OS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-os

I bought a Chromebook. I really like it, but for one thing: since I am in Canada, it comes with this horrible bilingual keyboard that has half length Shift and Enter keys, with the other half as extra backslash keys.

I'm awful with Javascript, but by following along from the code [here](https://github.com/google/extra-keyboards-for-chrome-os), I've managed to remap the right backslash to an enter key with the following code:

```
var context_id = -1;

chrome.input.ime.onFocus.addListener(function(context) {
  context_id = context.contextID;
});

chrome.input.ime.onKeyEvent.addListener(
  function(engineID, keyData) {
    var handled = false;

    if (keyData.code == "Backslash") {
        keyData.key = "Enter";
        keyData.code = "Enter";
        chrome.input.ime.sendKeyEvents({"contextID": context_id, "keyData": [keyData]});
        handled = true;
        }

    return handled;
  })
```

I figured the same trick would work for the Shift key:

```
    if (keyData.code == "IntlBackslash") {
    keyData.key = "ShiftLeft";
    keyData.code = "ShiftLeft";
    chrome.input.ime.sendKeyEvents({"contextID": context_id, "keyData": [keyData]});
    handled = true;
    }
```

Unfortunately, this does not work as I expected. The `IntlBackslash` key no longer makes a backslash, which is a step in the right direction, but it also does not seem to behave as a shift key.

Please help! I don't want to have to return this thing but the tiny shift key makes it unusable!

Comment: Try changing keyData.key to "Shift" or setting keyData.shiftKey: true. Also, you can check key and code values at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code#Try_it_out

Comment: @DanielHerr I tried both of those, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps setting .shiftKey: true on normal keypresses.